# How do you split a byte into sets of 2 and then rotate them using C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am currently learning bitwise operations in C.

Given a byte(spaced for readability): 11 01 11 10

Must turn it into: 10 11 01 11

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You got two `11`s in your example, which looks confusing. Can you make it clear what do you mean by rotation, or can you give more examples?

Comment: another example: 12 34 56 78 -> 78 56 34 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mask and shift:

```
int a = 0b11011110;
int b = ((a & 0b11000000) >> 6) |
        ((a & 0b00110000) >> 2) |
        ((a & 0b00001100) << 2) |
        ((a & 0b00000011) << 6);
```

I used binary constants here, but in "real life" you'll more often see hex - use whichever makes the most sense and reads best for your use case.

```
int b = ((a & 0xc0) >> 6) |
        ((a & 0x30) >> 2) |
        ((a & 0x0c) << 2) |
        ((a & 0x03) << 6);
```